# Load linearized PDF in React / Dot Net Core?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

There is a scenario in which I want to use linearized PDF or progressivly render PDF in react application.

I serached for linearlized PDF or loading PDFs in stream but didn't found any good solution. Has anyone has load PDF in streams or used linearied PDF.

Answer (score 0):

A linearized PDF will be read progressively by a PDF library which knows how to do that. Only byte-ranges in the file required for showing, for example, page one will be loaded to begin with. A PDF library which doesn't know about linearization will just load the whole file without regard to linearization information.

So, for linearization to work, you need a PDF library which knows about it, but also a transport mechanism (such as modern HTTP) which supports loading only certain byte ranges over the network. A third stipulation, of course, is that your PDF files must be linearized in the first place to benefit.

To clarify: linearization is about loading only such byte ranges containing objects required for each page. If you meant something different by "progressively render" the answer may lie elsewhere. Any PDF reader will do its best to parse only objects required for each page: linearization is about the progressive fetching of the actual bytes of the file.